# Centralities in networkx weighted graph

Tags: networkx, weighted-graph

I am not able to compute centralities for a simple  NetworkX weighted graph.
Is it normal or I am rather doing something wrong?

I add edges with a simple `add_edge(c[0],c[1],weight = my_values)`, where 
`c[0],c[1]` are strings  (names of the nodes) and `my_values` integers, within a for loop. This is an example of the resulting edges:

```
('first node label', 'second node label', {'weight': 14})
```

(the number of nodes does't really matter — for now I keep it to only 20)

The edge list of my graph is a list of tuples, with (string_node1,string_node2,weight_dictionary) - everything looks fine, as I am also able to draw/save/read/ the graph...

Why?:

- `nx.degree_centrality` gives me all 1s ?
- `nx.closeness_centrality` gives me all 1s ?

example:

```
{'first node name': 1.0,
...
'last node name': 1.0}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you post a complete (non)working example it will be easier to discover what the problem is.

Comment: yeah, I understand, but I am a bit scared for the sensibility of the data - names of real people, still alive. I can tell that I just fixed this 'issue' by adding the `weight='weight'` to `nx.clustering` , `nx.degree_assortativity_coefficient` and `nx.betweenness_centrality` ...that's why I am wondering if I can  really get the _weighted degree_ with the implemented  functions...probably I have to define my own, in order to compute the weighted degree...even if this seems a bit weird to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was easy:

instead of using `nx.degree_centrality()` I use
 `my_graph.degree(weight='weight')` - still I think this is a basic lack in the module...

...but, the issue is *still open* for `nx.closeness_centrality`

Answer (score 4):

For making `closeness_centrality` consider weight, you have to add a `distance` attribute of `1 / weight` to graph edges, as suggested in [this issue](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/860).

Here's code to do it (graph is `g`):

```
g_distance_dict = {(e1, e2): 1 / weight for e1, e2, weight in g.edges(data='weight')}
nx.set_edge_attributes(g, g_distance_dict, 'distance')
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a pretty old question, but just wanted to point out that the reason why your degree centrality values are all 1 is probably because your graph is complete (i.e., all nodes are connected to every other node), and degree centrality refers to the proportion of nodes in the graph to which a node is connected.

Per [networkx's documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.degree_centrality.html#networkx.algorithms.centrality.degree_centrality):

> The degree centrality for a node v is the fraction of nodes it is connected to.
>
> The degree centrality values are normalized by dividing by the maximum possible degree in a simple graph n-1 where n is the number of nodes in G.